# Cant Dismiss UIAlertController From Separate Function

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertcontroller, dismiss

I have a UIAlertController with no buttons (I use this alert as a please wait while some data loads message) that I present in the viewDidLoad function of my view controller. After I present the alert I run a function which retrieves information from a database and once this is done I want to dismiss the alert so the user can proceed however the alert does not seem to dismiss after running:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have also tried passing my uialertcontroller as an argument to the function and running the following line with no luck:

```
alertController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

EDIT: This is my viewDidLoad function as well as the function that should dismiss the alert

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading", message:
        "This might take a moment", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    hideAlert(alert: alertController)
}

func hideAlert(alert: UIAlertController) {
let hideAlertController = { () -> Void in 
alertController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            hideAlertController()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one inside your ViewController:

```
var operationPerformed : Bool = false;
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning();
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated);
    if(!self.operationPerformed){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading", message:
            "This might take a moment", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        self.performOperation(alertToBeClosedOnFinish: alertController);
    }
}

func performOperation(alertToBeClosedOnFinish: UIAlertController) {
    let hideAlertController = { () -> Void in
        alertToBeClosedOnFinish.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            hideAlertController();
            self.operationPerformed = true;
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is to show alert controller when it's owner is in hierarchy and if i understand you right - you want to call it once, so you should check if the operation has already been performed.

But disadvantage of such approach is trying to use alert controller when you can create your progress view as a subclass of UIView and add it or remove it to/from superview. Moreover, there are plenty of pods that can help you achieve this.

Best regards,
Sergey

Answer (score 2):

Let show the alert in the `viewDidAppear(_:)` methods. If not, you will get an error **whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Loading", message:
        "This might take a moment", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func hideAlert(alert: UIAlertController) {

    let hide = { () -> Void in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!) { (data, response, error) in

        print("error: \(error)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            hide()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And it's working!

[image]

Comment: I have tried to dismiss the alert in viewDidAppear just after presenting it however it was not dismissed (sorry if I misunderstood what you were trying to suggest)

Comment: I assumed to load data from a url and hide the alert when it's done. You can see my update!

Comment: I'm actually retrieving data from a firebase realtime database  which does run on a thread separate from the main one however calling the closure inside of DispatchQueue.main.async  does not work for me.

Comment: I think you should post more code, then people can help you

Comment: I just edited my original post now containing the closure call inside of my call to the firebase database hopefully that clears up what my issue looks like.

Comment: yes, let try to print anything like this `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("info").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot) in
            print("Hello")
        })`. Can you see the `Hello` string in the Console window?

Comment: @DanHuynh Yes it does print

Comment: What's `hideAlertController()`?

Comment: Sorry just noticed I forgot to put that in the last edit, hideAlertController is the closure that dismisses the alert

Answer (score 0):

Is the function which retrieves information from the database running on a different thread? If so, you can't update the UI from that thread. UI updates can only occur on the main thread.

What happens when you wrap your code with this? :)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    alertController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I just updated the original post also as I said in the edit I forgot to mention that I try to dismiss the alert inside of a closure which does run on a separate thread however after wrapping the dismiss call in the async it did not dismiss (I also tried wrapping the call to the closure with the async with the same results)